# Resize map in a MapActivity

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragmentactivity

I want to launch a MapActivity but with the map occupying only part of the screen, so to put information on the other party. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fragment to achieve your goal. For example :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" />
       <!-- here remaining layout-->


</RelativeLayout>
```

Fragment is used for google map and width defined to match_parent and hieght to 100dp. You can define you layout below this fragment or customize  this according your need.